# Assigning Array of objects from const to array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

So im trying to populate an Array to then pass a prop to another Component.

```
const arrayList = (): ArrayList[] => {
let remaining: number = 0
let stateArrayList: String[] = []
for (let i = 0; remaining > i; i++) {
    stateArrayList.push("Blah")
}
return (arrayList)
```

Results in the following error

```
Type '() => String[]' is missing the following properties from type 'String[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 27 more.  TS2322
```

I have looked around online using the TS2322 issue code, but cant seem to find a resolution.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Please consider editing the code to constitute a [mcve] as described by the guidelines for [ask].  As it stands it references undefined types like `ArrayList` and seems to be incomplete (there's at least a missing closing brace).  It does seem like the main problem is likely to be that you're returning the function itself instead of `stateArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You're returning `arrayList` (the function) but I think you wanted actually to return `stateArrayList` (the array).

Like this :

```
const arrayList = (): ArrayList[] => {
  let remaining: number = 0
  let stateArrayList: String[] = []
  for (let i = 0; remaining > i; i++) {
      stateArrayList.push("Blah")
  }
  return stateArrayList
}
```